# simpleinjector 3.0 not supporting RegisterManyForOpenGeneric

Tags: c#, simple-injector

So I decided to upgrade my version of simpleinjector to 3.0, and all of a sudden I get a message:

> 'SimpleInjector.Extensions.OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(SimpleInjector.Container, System.Type, params System.Reflection.Assembly[])' is obsolete: 'This extension method has been removed. Please use Container.Register(Type, IEnumerable) instead.

The documentation still has this method in there:

http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html

So I'm curious, what's the alternative to:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventHandler<>),
                                     container.RegisterAll,
                                     typeof(IEventHandler<>).Assembly);
```

Comment: The `latest` version of the docs still point at 2.8 (that's wrong of course). If you look [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/3.0/advanced.html) you'll see the new documentation.

Comment: That is not the compiler message that you'll get for the code you show in your question. The actual compiler error is: "This extension method has been removed. Please use Container.RegisterCollection(Type, IEnumerable<Assembly>) instead.". This message is pretty clear. You might have been looking at the wrong compiler error?

Comment: Not exactly, it was a direct copy and paste. I just uncommented the previous statement for RegisterManyForOpenGeneric, just to confirm this, and the error I posted is correct, it's saying Register, not RegisterCollection.

Comment: That is weird. I copy-pasted your code and on my machine it gives the error message above. I'm not sure how this can happen. I agree that the message you are getting is confusing. I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Steven actually the Register is correct, I updated my answer below. That solved my issue. RegisterCollection would involve me to change the configuration of my code a bit more. I didn't know I needed to add new[] in the second parameter. The documentation explained everything, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahh.. after scratching my head for several hours, <del>I figured it out</del>:

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IEventHandler<>),
                             typeof(IEventHandler<>).Assembly);
```

`RegisterCollection` handles open generics as well. Maybe this should be documented somewhere.

EDIT:

I realized in the new documentation, the above code is not a direct translation from RegisterManyForOpenGeneric. All it did was solve my compilation, but it didn't register my handlers, I just checked it today.

`Additional information: No registration for type`

This is the correct version:

```
container.Register(typeof(IEventHandler<>),
                   new[] { typeof(IEventHandler<>).Assembly });
```

Using a RegisterCollection would require some extra code changes (from the document):

> Because we register a collection, we can no longer call container.GetInstance>(). Instead instances can be retrieved by having an IEnumerable> constructor argument or by calling container.GetAllInstances>().

Which I haven't done, and don't really need to do since I don't have mixed open-generic and non-generics. But I'll explore this more in the future if I wanna revamp my project.

Comment: That's what you get when you're an early adapter. The documentation is being generated as we speak. It will be updated in a couple of minutes.

Comment: the documentation explained a lot, thanks.. I updated my answer